# Issue with radio button while freezing column using freeze-table.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have radio button in first column and I was trying to freeze first three columns. After selecting radio button, if I scroll, the radio button is showing as not selected. May I know why this is happening. (I'm guessing the issue with is clone table).

Here is code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".table-multi-columns").freezeTable({
      'columnNum': 3,
      'headWrapStyles': { 'top': '0' }
    });
})
```

```css
clone-head-table-wrap { margin-top: 0; }

.header {
    height: 150px;      
}

#header-sroll {
    position:fixed;
    height: 70px;
    background: rgb(255 115 37 / 75%);
    left:0;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    -ms-transition:     all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:         all 0.3s ease-out;

}
#header-sroll h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
     -ms-transition:    all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:         all 0.3s ease-out;
}
#header-sroll.small {
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 40px;
    z-index: 99;
}
#header-sroll.small h1{
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yidas.github.io/jquery-freeze-table/dist/js/freeze-table.js"></script>

<div class="container-md">
<h3>Fixed Table Header & Columns Demo</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eu lorem sed pellentesque. Fusce finibus nisl in lectus vehicula pulvinar. Morbi dolor ligula, rutrum at est ultricies, vestibulum varius sapien. Donec a bibendum sem. Nunc ultricies, orci eu pellentesque pretium, quam sem condimentum libero, id accumsan lorem arcu nec metus. Nam sodales nulla non turpis interdum, ut auctor diam varius. Ut sit amet magna placerat, sagittis tellus ut, convallis augue. Integer id orci ac nunc finibus interdum tristique et augue.</p>

<p>LProin vel scelerisque odio. Etiam ut hendrerit massa. Cras sit amet consequat risus. Maecenas ac magna non purus ultricies maximus ac accumsan leo. Nam condimentum maximus orci sed ornare. Nullam nec ipsum mi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Maecenas lectus dui, gravida at odio semper, vulputate facilisis libero. Sed vitae aliquet orci. Nam in orci vitae felis accumsan fringilla.</p>

<p>LDuis ut euismod justo, id gravida nisl. Vivamus nec orci nec quam sollicitudin luctus. Proin est quam, viverra quis lorem et, euismod finibus velit. Proin ultricies aliquam nisl eget lacinia. Donec nulla risus, fringilla ac imperdiet quis, placerat commodo turpis. Nam tristique, ante ut accumsan venenatis, felis nisi hendrerit nunc, eget sagittis dolor est a dolor. Quisque augue erat, lacinia ut posuere in, pellentesque ut ex. Nullam congue elit lorem, imperdiet elementum nibh suscipit id.</p>

<div class="table-multi-columns table-fill">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="table table-small-font table-bordered table-striped" style="min-width: 3400px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">#</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Date</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Text</th>
          <th colspan="2">Bank (1930)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Eget kapital John Doe (2010)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Eget kapital Jane Doe (2020)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Utgående moms 25 % (2610)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Moms varuförvärv EU 25 % (2615)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Ingående moms 25 % (2640)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Ingående moms utland (2645)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Moms redovisningskonto (2650)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Momspliktiga intäkter (3000)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Inköp varor EU 25 % (4056)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Förbrukningsinventarier (5400)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Kontorsmaterial och trycksaker (6100)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Övriga externa tjänster (6500)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Bankavgifter (6570)</th>
          <th colspan="2">Årets resultat (8999)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th data-columns="ledger-col-0">
          <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1"></label>
          </div>
          </th>
          <td data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-1">2014-01-11</td>
          <td data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-2">Office stuff</td>
          <td>100 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>25 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>75 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-columns="ledger-col-0">
          <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option1" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2"></label>
          </div>          
          </th>
          <td data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-1">2014-02-12</td>
          <td data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-2">iPad</td>
          <td>5000 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1250 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>3750 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-columns="ledger-col-0">
          <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option1" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3"></label>
          </div>          
          </th>
          <td data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-1">2014-03-20</td>
          <td data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-2">Office stuff</td>
          <td>100 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>25 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>75 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-columns="ledger-col-0">
          <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios4" value="option1" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4"></label>
          </div>          
          </th>
          <td data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-1">2014-04-11</td>
          <td data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-2">iPhone</td>
          <td>7000 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1750 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>5250 SEK</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th data-columns="ledger-col-0"></th>
        <th data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-1"></th>
        <th data-priority="1" data-columns="ledger-col-2"></th>
        <th>12 200 SEK</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>3050 SEK</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>8000 SEK</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>150 SEK</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
    <p>LDuis ut euismod justo, id gravida nisl. Vivamus nec orci nec quam sollicitudin luctus. Proin est quam, viverra quis lorem et, euismod finibus velit. Proin ultricies aliquam nisl eget lacinia. Donec nulla risus, fringilla ac imperdiet quis, placerat commodo turpis. Nam tristique, ante ut accumsan venenatis, felis nisi hendrerit nunc, eget sagittis dolor est a dolor. Quisque augue erat, lacinia ut posuere in, pellentesque ut ex. Nullam congue elit lorem, imperdiet elementum nibh suscipit id.</p>

<p>LAenean rhoncus eros et dui tincidunt, non faucibus mauris condimentum. Mauris felis nisi, accumsan non magna ut, dignissim dapibus dui. Fusce est magna, aliquet ac pellentesque a, varius eu tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce nec metus vitae magna rhoncus porttitor ac non sem. Nullam elementum velit eu metus mollis sodales. Morbi vitae nisl fringilla, congue mauris id, maximus metus. Morbi ut quam ut diam dignissim viverra non id dui. Sed ut rhoncus lacus. Praesent condimentum ultrices neque, sit amet porttitor mi sollicitudin ac.</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eu lorem sed pellentesque. Fusce finibus nisl in lectus vehicula pulvinar. Morbi dolor ligula, rutrum at est ultricies, vestibulum varius sapien. Donec a bibendum sem. Nunc ultricies, orci eu pellentesque pretium, quam sem condimentum libero, id accumsan lorem arcu nec metus. Nam sodales nulla non turpis interdum, ut auctor diam varius. Ut sit amet magna placerat, sagittis tellus ut, convallis augue. Integer id orci ac nunc finibus interdum tristique et augue.</p>

<p>LProin vel scelerisque odio. Etiam ut hendrerit massa. Cras sit amet consequat risus. Maecenas ac magna non purus ultricies maximus ac accumsan leo. Nam condimentum maximus orci sed ornare. Nullam nec ipsum mi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Maecenas lectus dui, gravida at odio semper, vulputate facilisis libero. Sed vitae aliquet orci. Nam in orci vitae felis accumsan fringilla.</p>

<p>LDuis ut euismod justo, id gravida nisl. Vivamus nec orci nec quam sollicitudin luctus. Proin est quam, viverra quis lorem et, euismod finibus velit. Proin ultricies aliquam nisl eget lacinia. Donec nulla risus, fringilla ac imperdiet quis, placerat commodo turpis. Nam tristique, ante ut accumsan venenatis, felis nisi hendrerit nunc, eget sagittis dolor est a dolor. Quisque augue erat, lacinia ut posuere in, pellentesque ut ex. Nullam congue elit lorem, imperdiet elementum nibh suscipit id.</p>

<p>LAenean rhoncus eros et dui tincidunt, non faucibus mauris condimentum. Mauris felis nisi, accumsan non magna ut, dignissim dapibus dui. Fusce est magna, aliquet ac pellentesque a, varius eu tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce nec metus vitae magna rhoncus porttitor ac non sem. Nullam elementum velit eu metus mollis sodales. Morbi vitae nisl fringilla, congue mauris id, maximus metus. Morbi ut quam ut diam dignissim viverra non id dui. Sed ut rhoncus lacus. Praesent condimentum ultrices neque, sit amet porttitor mi sollicitudin ac.</p>
```

Comment: Why - is most likely to create the "fixed" column, it's duplicated into a floating div.  Which means the radios are duplicated, so different radios - and you can only have one radio in the group selected at a time.  No idea of a fix with freeze-table.js, maybe they have something in their api documentation?

Comment: Yes I have requirement where I need to freeze first 3 columns in the table including with radio buttons. I have checked thier documention and I could not any found solution.